getting response using in frontend but noting with postman
public ResponseEntity<List<SalleResponse>> getAvailableSalles(
        @RequestParam("checkIndate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate checkInDate,
        @RequestParam("checkOutdate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)LocalDate checkOutDate,
        @RequestParam("salletype") String salleType) throws SQLException {
    List<Salle> availableSalles = salleService.getAvailableSalles(checkInDate, checkOutDate, salleType);
    List<SalleResponse> salleResponses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Salle salle : availableSalles){
        byte[] imageBytes = salleService.getSalleImageBySalleId(salle.getId());
        if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.length > 0){
            String imageBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageBytes);
            SalleResponse salleResponse = getSalleResponse(salle);
            salleResponse.setImage(imageBase64);
            salleResponses.add(salleResponse);
        }
    }
    if(salleResponses.isEmpty()){
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }else{
        return ResponseEntity.ok(salleResponses);
    }
}

why im getting a list of salles in frontend using axios get  but using postman i don't get anything i only get no content while im using the same approach in another function and im getting the right response both in frontend and postman?
